# Ubuntu crashes with blank screen

Tags: 16.04, crash, ntp

I have installed 32 bit Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (Kernel 4.4.0-53-generic). I have got strange problem after running for a few hours. The system crashes with black screen, and NOTHING works(like the system is shutdown)! I then manually started the system, and checked the /var/log/syslog file, and there are several lines like below before the system crashed.

```
Dec 13 09:36:06 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.94.4
Dec 13 09:36:07 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 46.4.54.78
Dec 13 09:36:07 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 193.175.73.151
Dec 13 09:36:13 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 131.234.137.64
Dec 13 09:37:10 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 2001:638:504:2000::36
Dec 13 09:37:13 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.198
Dec 13 09:37:13 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 129.70.132.34
Dec 13 09:37:14 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 178.162.194.82
Dec 13 09:37:17 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 144.76.14.132
Dec 13 09:38:16 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 2001:a60::123:1
Dec 13 09:38:18 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 176.9.41.109
Dec 13 09:38:18 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 213.95.21.43
Dec 13 09:38:19 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.199
Dec 13 09:38:24 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 188.68.58.36
Dec 13 09:39:22 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 176.9.82.67
Dec 13 09:39:22 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 5.9.49.12
Dec 13 09:39:24 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 129.70.132.36
Dec 13 09:39:26 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c7
Dec 13 09:39:30 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 5.9.44.47
Dec 13 09:40:28 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 213.172.105.106
Dec 13 09:40:29 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 46.4.54.78
Dec 13 09:40:29 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 95.142.67.61
Dec 13 09:40:30 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8
Dec 13 09:40:34 fremb0008 ntpd[1559]: Soliciting pool server 131.234.137.64
```

Note: the system does NOT have internet connection.

Is it normal to have this messages? I am not sure whether NTP server is crashing the system. I need your help guys!

**EDIT**

The output of *lspci | grep VGA*

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
```

and output of */proc/cpuinfo*

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 55
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2930  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x829
cpu MHz     : 2165.760
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3660.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 55
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2930  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x829
cpu MHz     : 2165.760
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3660.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 55
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2930  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x829
cpu MHz     : 2165.760
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3660.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 55
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2930  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x829
cpu MHz     : 2165.760
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3660.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: May you add the output of the commands `lspci | grep vga` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: you definitely have an internet connection. without functioning dns there is no way your ntpd would be querying pool servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You have a Bay-Trail CPU which has been known to cause issues with Ubuntu regarding sleep states.

Do the following:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add the parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Once you do this, close Gedit and run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.

*This is a very dirty fix*. Please stay up-to-date with the latest kernels as this bug will most likely be patched in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick!!! I will test it and let you know.

Comment: I have tested with boot parameter `intel_idle.max=1`, still did not work. I found something related to C-State in Bios also, but no idea which has more priority.  I tried other parameters like `processor.max_cstate=0 idle=poll `, but nothing seems to work.  I have updated the Linux kernel to _4.4.0-53-generic_, no luck.

Comment: @KrishnaPaudel It's not `intel_idle.max=1`, it's `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. Also, your laptop supports 64-bit, and you should therefore be on Ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for informing the typo. I changed it and run it for whole night, problem still persisted. Finally, as you said, I upgraded the Kernel to 4.8.14, and let it running. Till now, its running without problem :)

Comment: still not fixed in 21.10. got this problem, too on 64 bit ubuntu. since i added that line as mentioned, it now rarely crashes into the black screen. still happens maybe about biweekly.