# Ubuntu 16.04.1 could not restart/shutdown completely

Tags: 16.04, grub2, lubuntu, shutdown, reboot

I have installed **Lubuntu 16.04.1 (32 bit) LTS** (*kernel:4.8.14-040814-generic*) in my panel PC. I have strange problem while rebooting or shutting down. Sometimes, the rebooting or shutting down sticks somewhere without complete reboot/shutdown. That is when I shutdown, I get the message "Reached Target Shutdown" and thats it. Nothing happens after this. For reboot also, it just reaches here, and could not restart, and I have to press the power button to start again.

***Tried already***

1. I have modified grub config file (`/etc/default/grub`) as suggested by many posts.

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force reboot=bios,acpi,pci"*
   ```

   restarting after updating GRUB, nothing happens.
2. I have also checked messages while shutdown by enabling debug-shell, everything seems OK. No error message in the console, the last line is

   **`Reached Target Shutdown`**

***Information:***

1) `sudo lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SDIO Controller (rev 0e)
00:13.0 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA IDE Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

2) `uname -a`

> Linux fremb0008 4.8.14-040814-generic #201612101431 SMP Sat Dec 10
>   19:50:39 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

3) Processor Information

```
Socket Designation: SOCKET 0
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Atom
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: 78 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 55, Stepping 8
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2930 @ 1.83GHz
    Voltage: 1.2 V
    External Clock: 83 MHz
    Max Speed: 2400 MHz
    Current Speed: 1830 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket BGA1155
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0032
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0033
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Fill By OEM
    Part Number: Fill By OEM
    Core Count: 4
    Core Enabled: 4
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu crashes with blank screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/860156/ubuntu-crashes-with-blank-screen) Why are you still with 32bit? And `i686` suggests **this is not Ubuntu**.

Comment: Hello CelticWarrior, you are right, it is NOT ubuntu. It is *Lubuntu*. The question indicated as duplicate was asked by me, that was different problem.

Comment: This is unrelated to the c-state bug, accepted answer to the other question (I am not sure that the c-state bug caused the other problem, but it most certainly does NOT cause this one and `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` will not fix this so NOT a dupe of that

Comment: That is not c-state related problem. I already changed maximum cstates in bios and in grub also, but did not solve this problem. (I guess it was bug in kernel 4.4, and I have already newest kernel 4.8).

Answer (score 1):

After several days of debugging, I came up with the idea of upgrading the kernel of my system which seems to work so far (that is it does not do panic shutdown/restart)

I had kernel 4.8.14 installed which was causing the problem of improper shutdown/restart. I upgraded to 4.10.0 and now everything seems working so far. If some of you guys are also facing similar issues, I suggest to upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue i tried going to the recovery mode in the GRUB and using the fsck option. I tried everything else on all other posts and forums, it didn't work for me. But using the fsck option to repair the drive, it solved my issue.